# How to Add Smiley/Emojis in Edittext?

Tags: android

How to Add Smiley/Emojis in Edittext?

Any Source code is Available on Internet, if yes Please Give me Link.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am using below code for add Smiley/Emojis in edittext.

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happy);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return d;
    }
};

cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src='" + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happy) + "'/>", imageGetter, null);
edttxtemoji.setText(cs);
```

Comment: Hi Dipak, I have implement a textShortMessage for edit text so get the smiley code in android, i want to generate smiley image on the base of that obtain code in edit text but i can't get it. so can u please help any more please, i don't understand in your given code is that where i have to put this code.

Comment: I have one doubt so reply me fast.

Comment: yes, if metter of your code its perfectly working. but i am working on something else, i am just using that concept only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3231/discussion-between-amit-and-dipak-keshariya)

Comment: How to get Smiley's from Edittext into String Format? if u know then help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Android may not support some special characters, but here is the tutorial anyways:**

On a PC, I believe either Alt + 1 or Alt + 2 makes a smiley face.

[This website](http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/ALTchrc.html) provides an excellent tutorial for how to do alt codes, along with what alt code combination does what.

For a Mac, you can hold *"Option + Command + T"* down to open a list of special characters.  From there, open the category "Miscellaneous."  Your smiley is in there.

Is this what you are looking for?  If not, just let me know :).
When all else fails, you could just use an image of a smiley-face.

**EDIT:**  *I'm using a Mac.  I opened TextEdit, followed my above tutorial for the Mac, generated a smiley face, cut the smiley face, and pasted it into the Java code.  It worked for me.  If it's not working for you, try copying this:*

```
EditText mEditText = null;
mEditText.setText("☺");
```

**EDIT 2:** *I thought Martin was looking for just a smiley, not a window of Emoji's.  Currently, there is no source code to open this window - only a separate app that does this, which can be found at [this link](http://jeftek.com/707/emoji-with-android-and-iphone/) or [this link](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pansi.msg.plugin.emoji&feature=search_result).*

Comment: Hello Mike Gates, how to help this link to display smiley in android edit text?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand _exactly_ what you're looking for.  If you want a smiley to appear in Android's `EditText`, couldn't you just follow the little tutorial in the answer I provided you and just put the smiley in the text field?

Comment: I'm assuming that Android doesn't support a smiley face as a special character.  Try some of the other alt codes in the link I provided to you.  Do any of those work?

Comment: Take a look at the edit I just added to the bottom of my response.  Try doing that. If you have a PC, just use Notepad instead of TextEdit.

Comment: Not Work & second thing is android support a smiley face.             any other code is used for smiley face?

Comment: I did a little research in the mean time, and I couldn't find any other way to generate a smiley - that is, your only two options are with alt codes or opening a special character list to choose from.

Comment: Maybe this is your problem - are you trying to use the numbers above your keys (the numbers on the top of your keyboard), or are you using the key pad (the one that looks like a phone pad)?  To use alt codes, as far as I know, you must use the keypad.

Comment: if android support smiley face then give link of application in which smiley is in EditText

Comment: I added code to my response.  Try copying it and see if that works for you.

Comment: Your Added Code is not Working, & following is link for smiley supported application.                             https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pansi.msg.plugin.emoji&feature=search_result

Comment: My code works if you add `import android.widget.EditText;`.  I thought you were just looking for a way to add a simple smiley to an application, not a whole window of Emojis.  I did some research, and I have to say that from what I've seen, there is an app that allows you to add Emojis (like in the link you provided), but I don't think there is any source code you can use to add them to an app.

Comment: video and screenshot of that app is dofferent..i didnt find any simley in video