# Android Custom Keyboard with unusual symbols

Tags: android, keyboard

Hi guys i am wonder whether it is possible to create a custom keyboard in Android such as the once attached with this question. Any ideas and clue would be very much appreciated. Hoping for better response. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered about that in the past and I ended up using a custom View, assigning the active `EditText` element to it, hiding the system keyboard and changing the content when a button is pressed.

Comment: Will we be able to key-in the selected item on the edittext as we do for normal characters and symbols?

Comment: You can add an activeEdit property to your Keyboard View, have your EditText elements know your keyboard and override the `onFocusChanges()` method in order to change the activeEdit attribute to the current EditText. Then, on any key event, you could just modify the Text by calling `activeEdit.getEditableText().insert(activeEdit.getSelectionStart(), yourTextString);`.

Comment: Can you please explain in more details... also can you please tel me whether i can detect the key that i am touching on the custom keyboard and then adding the corresponding image to the edit text. And i found [this link for adding image inside edittext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189903/how-to-add-smiley-emojis-in-edittext)