# Smiles and long press feature in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

I've created an Android keyboard. How do I add features like inserting smilies, and using long keypresses to display symbols?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189903/how-to-add-smiley-emojis-in-edittext

Answer (score 0):

To create long-press behavior that allows to select several options from a pop-up menu, follow this guide (specifically the pop-up menu section):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Smileys (also known as emoticons) are simply a combination of keys, that are understood by all programs and parsed the same way. So what you have to do, is when someone clicks the smiley face on your keyboard, simulate the pressing of the key combination matching that emoticon. For example, when someone clicks a smiley, you should simulate the key presses ':' and ')' to get :).

Here's a list of emoticons:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons